# How to call session value by key and value name

Tags: php, arrays, session

Below is the session I defined:

```
$_SESSION['addons'][] = array(
   'addon'    => $addon_id,
   'quantity' => $qty,
   'date_a'   => $date_1,
   'date_b'   => $date_2,
   'car_id'   => $car_id,
   'pickup'   => $location,
   'drop'     => $d_location
);
```

I'm calling it in this way:

```
<?php
foreach($_SESSION['addons'] as $addon=>$add_val)
{
    //echo $addon;
    foreach($add_val as $value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }
}
?>
```

Currently it displays all value and the the values are displayed correctly but I want them to be called by the name I set specifically in the session.For instance,

```
$value['addon'];
```

So that I can choose which value to call and which not.

I tried something like this:

```
//setting adon id as key and the rest as value  but doesn't work in the way I wanted.
$_SESSION['addons'][$addon_id] = array(
   'quantity' => $qty,
   'date_a'   => $date_1,
   'date_b'   => $date_2,
   'car_id'   => $car_id,
   'pickup'   => $location,
   'drop'     => $d_location
);
```

Comment: your second `foreach` is doing exactly what it is supposed to do - looping through the keys in the "value" variable of $add_val, and outputting any values it finds. Why doesn't the second method work, exactly? I don't know the scope of your application, but I would generally suggest using an object instead of the `$_SESSION` variable for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the `add_val` is the array of each addon, so `echo add_val['addon'];` will contain the `$addon_id`.

You had where you were going, you just went a bit too deep

Comment: I tried this way, But for some reason  the echo add_val['addon']; repeats for 6 times?

Comment: if it is inside the second for loop, it will be called each iteration. put it where you have `//echo $addon;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you wish to see the value for a particular key directly. You may initialize the session like:

```
$_SESSION['addons'] = array('addon'=>$addon_id,'quantity'=>$qty,'date_a'=>$date_1,'date_b'=>$date_2,'car_id'=>$car_id,'pickup'=>$location,'drop'=>$d_location);
```

and then for example if you wish to echo the value for the key "date_a" you can do:

```
echo $_SESSION['addons']['date_a'];
```

Hope this helps!